# Rails manipulate model query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Assume I have `params[:foo] = "bar"` and some saved object whose `attribute = "key.bar"`
How can I manipulate `Model.where(attribute: params[:foo])` to query for `attribute.split(".")[1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if there's a better way, but the first method that popped in my mind is using the `LIKE` operator. You can write your query thusly:

```
Model.where("attribute LIKE '%?'", params[:foo])
```

Note, given the example you posted, I placed the wildcard (`%`) in that position so that the attribute is match for anything that ends with your parameter. This assumes all your attributes are similar to what you described, but you can of course change it around to your liking.

Also, while I've never used it myself, I understand that the [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem provides this functionality as an operator (described [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#predicates)).

Answer (score 0):

Small change to answer above

```
Model.where("attribute LIKE '%.?'", params[:foo])
```

to prevent matching both .bar and .foobar.